# Redirecting Report Server connections using host file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssrs

I am connected remotely to a server called New_Server and trying to connect to the Report Server which is installed on it by referring to another server:

I've changed the **host file** on NEW_SERVER to POINT to ITSELF when referring to another server: if I put in Old_Server name, it SHOULD point to itself; NEW_Server

So I put in this link: http://New_Server/ReportServer/ - it works
But then when I put in the link: http://OLD_SERVER/ReportServer/
then it asks me to RE-AUTHENTICATE, which I do, but it doens't seem to respond at all. It just seem to get my input and do nothing with it (since I am reprompted again and again for the username/password).

Issues:

1. Why should it even ask me to re-authenticate; should it NOT just replace "Old_Server" with "New_Server"? So shouldn't it just connect to 
   http://New_Server/ReportServer/ ??
2. Why does it ask for, then ignore authentication?

It's worth mentioning that I've blocked the OLD_SERVER using firewall. But again, this should not matter since I changed the host to refer to itself when it's trying to access OLD_Server

*My research*:

1. I've read this blog about changing URLROOT, and again this is not
       something I want to do or am trying to achieve. I am trying to fool
       the server to *think* it's connecting to OLD_SERVER but then
       referring it to NEW_SERVER
2. Using CNAME/DNS Alias is not an option
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447582/windows-8-ie-cannot-reach-sites-listed-in-hosts-file - I've done the troubleshooting steps from that question.
4. https://support.solarwinds.com/Success_Center/Network_Performance_Monitor_(NPM)/Knowledgebase_Articles/Edit_the_host_file_to_add_static_entry_for_hosts_that_are_not_resolving_by_DNS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who's facing the same issue, following the steps in [this article](https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Enable_DNS_Alias_Names_to_Access_Windows_Server_Shares) fixed my issue. For some reason, it's required to make an adjustment in registry to allow for this use. Also, remember to add report server site as INTRANET (in Internet Option/security).